# Odd Silverlight 3 assembly reference error - StylePalette does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: silverlight

I have moved a project I was working on from one machine to another, and am now getting an error message when I attempt to build. The two machines should have the same software setup, but it appears they do not.
The error in question is:

> The tag 'StylePalette' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization; assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

And a chunk of the XAML in question:

```
<datavis:StylePalette
        x:Key="MyStylePalette">
    <!--Blue-->
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyPieDataPointTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2.09" ScaleY="1.819"/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-0.425" Y="-0.486"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB9D6F7"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF284B70" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have the latest Silverlight Toolkit installed on my new machine but am guessing the problem must be to do with that.

I had heard that StylePalette had been renamed to palette but this does not seem to exist in the toolkit namespace.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the new machine has an updated version of the Toolkit.

The `StylePalette` not longer exists, you should use the more general type `ResourceDictionaryCollection`.  Also properties original named `StylePalette` have been renamed to simply `Palette`.  See this [Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/10/19/silverlight-and-wpf-data-visualization-classes-unsealed-silverlight-toolkit-october-2009-release-now-available.aspx) on the issue.